# Best way to select items with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have read all about the best order of selectors in CSS but I often (all the time) see people doing this....

```
nav ul li#email-me a {
   width: 120px;
   height: 43px;
   background: url(images/email_me.png) no-repeat top left;
   display: block;
}
```

From what I have read, my understanding is that this is better for performance...

```
#email-me a {
   width: 120px;
   height: 43px;
   background: url(images/email_me.png) no-repeat top left;
   display: block;
}
```

Am I missing something?  Is the second method better?  If it is, why does everybody use the first method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use the first method, because

- As mentioned in [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317980/106224) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318037/106224) answers, it's more specific. An ID doesn't automatically make an entire rule more specific than any others forever; you can add a type selector — or pretty much anything except the universal selector `*` — to the ID and it'll immediately stomp out a rule with a lone ID selector. I don't find myself increasing a selector's specificity on purpose with this technique as much as I do it for organization, though...
- To elaborate on organization: this kind of rule is often related to other rules that start with `nav ul`, and it helps to visually group them with a few initial selectors that are already in place.

  For example:

  ```
  nav ul {
      /* Styles for the ul */
  }

  nav ul li {
      /* Styles for the items */
  }

  nav ul li a {
      /* Styles for the item links */
  }

  /* 
   * If the selector here were just #email-me a, it'd be impossible
   * to see, right away, how it's related to the above rules, without
   * studying the markup that it applies to, and so on.
   */
  nav ul li#email-me a {
      /* Styles for the link in the #email-me item */
  }
  ```

The second method is supposedly faster because no additional checks need to be performed after identifying the ancestor element with the ID, but I have no benchmarks and I can't be bothered to make any.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there's a specificity thing that people are trying to overcome; they just keep adding sections onto their selector until it's more specific than another.

But more likely is just ignorance and/or thoughtlessness.

We're better than them! :D

Comment: specificity is the word I was looking for!  What you described is what I thought but can't you target an item with ID and get to it no matter how nested it is?

Comment: Actually, I seldom do it just for specificity (although that's definitely a valid reason over such nonsensical issues as performance). More as a way to group my rules together in my stylesheet. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The second method is really not that much better than the first in terms of performance.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS), the style system starts with the key selector (in your example, `a`) and starts moving left, trying to match each element's ancestors in the DOM tree with the selector.

It's considered inefficient because the system first finds all `a` tags and traverses up the dom tree of each. If you had a thousand `a` tags on your page, it would need to traverse each one's ancestors in an attempt to match the selector. It would be more efficient to target a specific ID or class.

Realistically, unless you have a page with LOTS of elements, this is kind of a micro-optimization that you *usually* should not need to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example will probably perform better, but the question is weighing *performance* against *context*.

For example, in your second example, you are saying any anchor element that is a descendant of any element with an id of `email-me` should have a style. The question is: Is that what you really mean?

For example, if, on different page, another element were to use the id of `email-me`, lets say a `div` element, should links inside it get the same style? Is that really want you are saying? If it is, then great.

If not, however, do you really mean the context described in the first example: Only anchors, that are descendants of a list item with an id of `email-me`, that are descendants of an un-ordered list that are inside of the navigation section of a page.

I would argue, like [I have before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166522/div-classname-in-css-file/7167321#7167321), that it really depends on what you are trying to say. But I would say that most of the time, sacrificing specificity/clarity for performance isn't a good trade.

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat up to personal choice. A small defense of the first selector you showed: It shows a better chain of context. It can be helpful, when scrolling through lots of CSS to see how that `#email-me` element fits. In your example, I can see it's part of the `nav` structure, which gives a hint to how it is used.

In terms of performance, the difference is extremely small (negligible).

However, in my opinion, the best CSS selector is the least CSS selector. So I vote for the second one.

Comment: Attaching the ID selector to a weak element selector ruins it.

Comment: @Mathletics: What do you mean by "ruins it"?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the selector would first select all the "a" elements, then check to find the one that has the #email-me as a parent. It's inefficient to use ID as parent selectors like that. But the performance hit is really small.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html

Read about specificity. It should come as no surprise that lots of people are doing it wrong.