# Custom tags... why not?

Tags: css, html, custom-tag

I found a site with an guide to add custom tags to html, the same way people make ie work with the new HTML5 tags. I must admit I think it would be great to add my own tags, would make it easier to "scan" the the code, and find what you are looking for.
But every site I found about it, people say it's not good.... but why isn't it good?

Example html with class:

```html
<ul class="commentlist">
    <li class="comment odd">
    <div class="1">
        <div class="avatar">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
        </div>
        <div class="metadata">
            <div class="name">Name</div>
            <p>response1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="comment even">
            <div class="2">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
                </div>
                <div class="metadata">
                    <div class="name">Name</div>
                    <p>response1a</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="comment odd">
            <div class="3">
                <div class="avatar">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
                </div>
                <div class="metadata">
                    <div class="name">Name</div>
                    <p>response1b</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here what I could do with custom tags, I think that would be much easier to find my way around, so why not:

```xml
<clist>
<ccommentbox class="odd">
    <ccomment class="1">
        <cavatar>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
        </cavatar>
        <cdata>
            <cname>Name</cname>
            <ctext>response1</ctext>
        </cdata>
    </ccomment>
    <cchildren>
        <ccommentbox class="even">
            <ccomment class="2">
                <cavatar>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
                </cavatar>
                <cdata>
                    <cname>Name</cname>
                    <ctext>response1a</ctext>
                </cdata>
            </ccomment>
        </ccommentbox>
        <ccommentbox class="odd">
            <ccomment class="3">
                <cavatar>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" width="60" height="60" />
                </cavatar>
                <cdata>
                    <cname>Name</cname>
                    <ctext>response1b</ctext>
                </cdata>
            </ccomment>
        </ccommentbox>
    </cchildren>
</ccommentbox>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7167321/814761) may be of interest to you (not exactly an answer, but explains the concept of tag context and customization very well).

Comment: It's really not as simple as you think.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Custom tags are not evil

**just consider this:**

- They are not recognized in IE 6-8 by default -> you have to use JavaScript to introduce each custom tag you use on the page e.g: `document.createElement('custom-tag')` This means **your website will only render correctly with JavaScript turned on**
- In most browsers your custom tags will be treated as inline elements like `<span>`, this means you have to write CSS to declare them as `custom-tag { display: block }`
- There is no resource I found that could proof that custom tags have any negative impact on search engines. In fact Google released [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) which promotes custom tags (`<pane>` and `<tab>`) in its examples on the **[front page](http://angularjs.org/)**.
- Most HTML Editors will mark your custom tags as invalid HTML, because they are not in the official spec.

### To summarize:

- Use custom tags when there are important elements that have more
  meaning than `<div>` and there is **no existing HTML 4/5
  equivalent**. This is especially true for web applications which
  parse the DOM for special tags/attributes/classes to create
  components (like Angular.js).
- If all you build is a **simple website** with normal content, stick
  to standard HTML. You will want your website to work also without
  JavaScript turned on.
- If you build a **web application** where custom tags could really
  help to make the source cleaner and express special semantics, use
  them. All negative implications mentioned above (JavaScript has to be
  turned on / CSS declaration) won't matter for these cases. The same
  rules apply to custom attributes.

For more details on this topic: [IE compatibility for Angular.js](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I would just add this for those put off by the "invalid" responses of some editors and validators.  

http://wheelcode.blogspot.com/2012/07/html-validation-is-bad.html

Comment: HTML validators can still be useful. Check your page every now and then during development to find typos in the markup like forgotten unclosed or non-matching elements. Especially if your editor doesn't support you with this. Sometimes these errors won't show up in most browsers immediately, yet they can cause pain in long hunting sessions about why that CSS doesn't work like it always did.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of reasons why you shouldn't do this.

1. **First:** By creating your own tags like that, you lose the functionality of tags like `ul and li`.  Your custom tags will just be generic divs, and that won't give you the results you are looking for.Yes, you can style the tags to duplicate those functions, but why spend all that time doing something that browser already does.
2. **Second:** People with disabilities will not be able to utilize your site, because it won't conform to any standard HTML. Those who are blind will use assistive technologies that read the html and present the contents verbally.

Another reason is that browsers and javascript don't always work really well with these custom tags.  You will likely run into more problems than you imagine. It will be harder to make your apps cross-platform if you do this.

Comment: I reset the ul and li, and define my own styling anyway :\

but yeah, screenreaders, another thing I haven't thought about :P

Comment: If it's purely about visual enhancements like character grouping in  long codes (think of IBAN or phone numbers) and you don't want to use U+2009 and the like for copy&paste, a little `<gap>` element for a `letter-spacing` style shouldn't hurt, right? Better then `<span class="gap">`...

Comment: @LonelyPixel - HTML is semantic, while styling is visual.  The point is that your HTML elements define something beyond visual.  For instance, the HTML5 `<header>` tag defines that its content is part of a header, but it does not define how that header should look.  If something is purely visual then it belongs in style.

Answer (score 5):

Elements defined in HTML have known semantics. These can be understood by browsers (especially useful if they don't have CSS support), screen readers, search engines, and any other user agent and then expressed to the user.

Your own elements are meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to use XSLT to transform your XML to valid HTML. If you introduce your own custom tag, you are no longer writing HTML, but probably XML or SGML.

Comment: It's not really that I want to use it, I was more wondering WHY I can't do it. What I'll mess up if I use it :P
Like the other answers: Searchbots, screenreaders and making crossbrowser harder to function :P

Answer (score -2):

Well, for one thing you'd have to define CSS for all of those custom elements to behave like you want them to (eg. make the `<ccommentbox>` appear like a list), which causes unnecessary CSS. It also makes it harder for search bots to understand your site.

Comment: ooh, searchbots xD haven't thought of that xD
but I already reset the lists i use for comments, and then makes them behave as I want to, so I can't see there will be much more styling :\

Comment: I really don't think search engines get anymore out of <div class="commentbox"> than they would out of <commentbox>.