# Use own tags instead of divs

Tags: class, html, tags

I working on a web app. Is it good to use own html tags than divs? I mean using own tags instead of classes. This will make it easier to bind up dynamic content by splitting up common classes with id.

Example

```
<div id="message">
My Message
</div>
```

Replace with this

```
<message>
   My message
</message>
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what document type you are using. If you are using HTML doctype declarations then you would have to comply with rules defined in the declaration. I'd suggest you stick with classes if that is the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom tags... why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906448/custom-tags-why-not)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want this, because now HTML5 supports a lot of semantic tags like `<audio>`, `<address>`, etc. Usually, you can achive block-effect (i.e. combining or grouping related content in a block) by `<div class="myblock"></div>` for special purposes. Anyway, as you've asked, then for your information—you can use custom tags in HTML. Also you can style those using CSS and can use selectors to perform operation on those using JavaScript.

**Note:** Prior IE9 versions don't support custom tags. Hence you should create your tags like this using JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('mytag');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main practical reason for not doing this is that IE 8 and older do not let you style your custom tags. As Vishal mentions, there’s a workaround to this, but it does not work when JavaScript is disabled. And as he points out, you can use the `class` attribute—you should use `id` only for uniquely identifying a single element.

You can also use `class` attributes for elements other than `div`. You can first select an element so that its default (non-CSS) rendering is the best possible (among available alternatives), then add a `class` attribute.

In CSS, you would then normally use a class selector without tag name, e.g. `.message` (if you use `class=message`).