# custom tags (like xml) within html page?

Tags: css, xml, html, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom tags… why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906448/custom-tags-why-not)

why is using custom tags in HTML a bad practice?

code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXr2L/1/ works just fine with browsers.

if i have to style a 100 random words on a webpage, using `<hg></hg>` would save lot of space and data instead of using `<span class="hg"></span>` . CSS also works fine with these custom tags. Only issue would be W3 HTML validity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is using custom tags in HTML a bad practice

You answered your own question.

> Only issue would be W3 HTML validity.

Are you working in a compnay where someone else may need to work with your code in the future?  Can you be certain that future browsers are going to be ok with your custom tags?  Can you be sure that older browsers will handle them?

Standards can obviously be broken, and if you want to do things your own way then you can.  However, standards are just that - STANDARDS.  Adhering to them can save you problems when things do not work and will ensure your code is the highest quality it can be.

Answer (score 0):

Test your fiddle in IE and you should have the answer.

tags defined in html are understood by browsers, your custom tags are meaningless to browsers and obvioulsy they wont work. If you need to create a custom tag, you should do this via javascript like `document.createElement('custom-tag');`

Comment: The doctype has nothing to do with the issue.