# How to prevent text from shrinking with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I have come across an unexpected behavior when using a flex box with overflow set to one of the items. It works as expected when on a browser, but on mobile, the left text shrinks to be almost unreadable.

This only seems to occur when the text is actually begins to overflow though.
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

```
    <style>

flexHolder{
    height:80%;
    display:flex;
}

rightSide{
    overflow: auto;
}


</style>

<flexHolder>
    <leftSide>
        Left
    </leftSide>
    <rightSide>
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right         Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
        Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right Right 
Right Right 
    </rightSide>
</flexHolder>
```

Comment: Aside: Are you working with an HTML processor? `flexHolder`, `leftSide`, and `rightSide` are not valid HTML elements

Comment: Those are just custom elements. They've been valid HTML for around 5 years now.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements

Comment: Have you added the appropriate viewport meta tags to your page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Dang it that was it. At least it was an easy fix. :)

Comment: @Robbie, apologies, I shouldnt say _not valid_, i mean have potential compatibility issues, and may required additional CSS, and/or JS to keep older browsers from bawking, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12611408/648350

Comment: FYI: custom html element must contain dashes.

Comment: To clarify TECHNICALLY they should have dashes, but from what I understand that is just to prevent issues with possible future tags. Most of my stuff is named so specifically that I doubt future tags will effect them.

Comment: @dommmm post an answer so that Robbie can accept it

Comment: @danyamachine okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the viewport meta tags necessary to scale the page:

[http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_t‌​ag](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_t%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bag)

Without the meta tag, on a smaller device the browser will simply render the page as it were on the desktop, hence the really small text size.