# Adding an overflow scroll-bar to a "checkbox" input type

Tags: html, css, checkbox, scroll, display

I am new to HTML/CSS.

I'm trying to add an overflow scroll-bar to a checkbox drop-down, the end use of which will be a laterally-scrolling image gallery that can be hidden by clicking on some text. In other words, I'd like to toggle a `<div>` to show and hide content on a page.

Currently, I'm able to click on some text and hide/show a table of images. What I'm having trouble with is enclosing the table `<div>` with an overflow `<div>`, which would allow the user to scroll side to side within the toggled table (that's the idea at least). I've written out, essentially, what I'm trying to do below, with the dysfunctional code:

**Ideal HTML**

```
<label for="my_checkbox"><h3>Show/hide</h3></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">

<div>
<div class="horizScroll">
<div class="horizTable">
    <horizArticle>
        <img src ="my_image.png">
    </horizArticle>
    <horizArticle>
        <img src ="my_image.png">
    </horizArticle>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Ideal CSS**

```
.horizScroll {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
}

.horizTable {
        display: none;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%
}

horizArticle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .horizTable{
    display: table;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .horizScroll{
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I've fiddled with this, but I haven't been able to get the table display *and* the overflow bar to co-exist simultaneously using the checkbox method. So I'm hoping someone here has the magic bullet to fix what I'm trying to accomplish. Below is the CSS/HTML that already works.

**Working HTML**

```
<label for="my_checkbox"><h3>Show/hide</h3></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox" style="display:none;">

<div class="horizTable">
    <horizArticle>
        <img src ="my_image.png">
    </horizArticle>
    <horizArticle>
        <img src ="my_image.png">
    </horizArticle>
</div>
```

**Working CSS**

```
.horizScroll {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
}

.horizTable {
        display: none;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 100%
}

horizArticle {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .horizTable{
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you explain what is `<horizArticle>` tag?

Comment: That tag sizes and helps organize the photo content within the checkbox container.

Comment: Understood, but why use a custom tag instead of something like `<div class="horizArticle" />`?

Comment: can you explain what you mean? what's the difference between how i've called it out, and how you're proposing it?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906448/custom-tags-why-not) can tell you what I mean, summarily custom tags are not always compatible, they don't provide a valid cross-platform solution and also if you're new to these languages, it's more probable that you're not developing a web application, so using custom tags in these cases is not compliant

Comment: thanks for that link. being relatively green to the world of HTML/CSS, this is a really great tip that i'll use on my site. i've already started scrubbing my pages of custom tags and replacing them as you recommended. cheers!