# When to use CSS classes and when to not?

Tags: html, css

When should you add classes to elements and style them using class selectors and when should you instead add a class/id on the parent and use the elements just as is?

Example:

```
<div class="warning-dialog">
    <h3>This is the title</h3>
    <p>This is the message</p>
</div>

.warning-dialog {}
.warning-dialog h3 {}
.warning-dialog p {}
```

vs.

```
<div class="warning-dialog">
    <h3 class="warning-title">This is the title</h3>
    <p class="warning-message">This is the message</p>
</div>

.warning-dialog {}
.warning-title {}
.warning-message {}
```

Or should you do

```
.warning-dialog .warning-dialog {}
.warning-dialog .warning-title {}
.warning-dialog .warning-message {}
```

Comment: I would argue that these are fundamentally semantically different, and aren't really comparable because they express entirely different things. My thoughts on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166522/div-classname-in-css-file/7167321#7167321

Comment: @32bitkid: How have I not seen that before...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ask yourself this simple question:

> Do all `<x>` elements under this common ancestor mean the same thing?

If the answer to that is yes, then you don't need a class name on those elements. Taking your code as an example, the following is sufficient:

```
<div class="warning-dialog">
    <h3>This is the title</h3>
    <p>This is the message</p>
</div>
```

Because inside of a `.warning-dialog`, all `h3` elements (1) and all `p` elements (1) would mean the same, the title and the content of the dialog! Meaning, you don't need to have any specific class names on them and they are easily accessible via `.warning-dialog h3` or `.warning-dialog p`.

If however, the answer to above question is "No", that's a whole different story:

```
<div>Warning</div>
<div>Info</div>
<div>Error</div>
```

You can't (easily) designate each div with a CSS, **they don't all mean the same thing**, so you need to use class names to make it better!

```
<div class="warning-dialog">Warning</div>
<div class="info-dialog">Info</div>
<div class="error-dialog">Error</div>
```

Comment: So basically you don't write for the future? In the way that you may add a `p` element? I understand that nobody can write code for the future but some parts are more likely to change more often.

Comment: You never said anything about future-proofing.

Comment: Why? Should you add a `p` element, you need to ask yourself AGAIN, do all `<p>` elements mean the same in `.warning-dialog`, if the answer is "yes" then you're clear, if not, add a classname!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how flexible you want/ need your styling to be.  Attaching CSS to parent tags means that all similar tags under the parent will have the same styling.  If some of them should/ could be different, you'll need a way to specifically set them.

```
<div class="foo">
    <div>stuff</div>
    <div>other stuff</div>
</div>
```

in this case, "stuff" and "other stuff" must have the same style (unless we start playing with `nth-child` and stuff).

Comment: No it won't... if I apply styles on "foo", not all of them will be inherited to its children divs! See http://dabblet.com/gist/2430570

Comment: @Truth: You misread my answer.  The divs containing "stuff" and "other stuff" will be styled identically; I mentioned nothing about the "foo" classed tag.

Answer (score 1):

Technically for both examples you could do with out classes. It would really only be the parent container that would make a difference. For example....

**If you were going to have multiple error containers on one page you could do something like this.**

```
<div class="warning-dialog">
    <h3>This is the title</h3>
    <p>This is the message</p>
</div>

.warning-dialog {
/*css for container*/
}

.warning-dialog h3 {
/*css for all h3 tags in that container*/
}

.warning-dialog p {
/*css for all p tags in that container */
}
```

**If you were only going to use that container once on the page you could do this.**

```
<div id="warning-dialog">
        <h3>This is the title</h3>
        <p>This is the message</p>
    </div>

    #warning-dialog {
    /*css for container*/
    }

    #warning-dialog h3 {
    /*css for all h3 tags in that container*/
    }

    #warning-dialog p {
    /*css for all p tags in that container */
    }
```

**And if you were going to use the same container but style the header tag differently in one of your containers you would then probably want to use a class on the p tag.. for example...**

```
<div class="warning-dialog">
        <h3 class="option2">This is the title</h3>
        <p>This is the message</p>
    </div>

    .warning-dialog {
    /*css for container*/
    }

    .warning-dialog h3 {
    /*css for all h3 tags in that container*/
    }

    .warning-dialog p {
    /*css for all p tags in that container */
    }

    .warning-dialog .option2 {
    /*css for option 2*/
    }
```

**However this may not always be the most practical approach because you will have conflicting CSS between these...And would have to use !important.**

```
.warning-dialog p {
    /*css for all p tags in that container */
    }

    .warning-dialog .option2 {
    /*css for option 2*/
    }
```

So instead it would probably still be best to have different ID's for the parent element. IE(errormsg1 and errormsg2) ...

But really it all depends on the context of your project.

Answer (score 0):

The base concept is, that

1. Unique Element to be styled, use `id`
2. Collection of similar elements to be styled, use `class`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's mainly a matter of personal preferences. I prefer to keep my HTML as clean as possible so I will prefer this

```
.warning-dialog {}
.warning-dialog h3 {}
.warning-dialog p {}
```

Also, if an element needs to be accessed by JavaScript, it's easier / faster to use an id instead of a class, but you have to make sure that you'll use that element only once in your page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your taste and personal preference; however, as some have pointed out, if all the children tags (of a particular type e.g. div) need the same style, you don't need to create a class for them; just use the tag names. If some require the same style, and others do not, apply classes to the ones that require (or don't require) it, and style accordingly. 
  If you feel that the content might change in the near future, and the new content will require different styling, you can add classes to the new tags as they are being created. 
   The point is that there's no defined standard way of doing it, and all everyone can tell you is what works for them.